# getting nth item of jquery array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have array object

```
users[{object1}; {object2}, {object3}];
```

where each object has attributes below

```
object.userId
object.userName
object.email
```

i am trying to get specific object when i click on span which represents each object.

For eg:- when i click on `span.id= 1`, i am trying to get the object from array which has `userid == 1`

i have tried, `jquery .eq(), grep() , get()` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Loop thorugh your objects and compare `users[i].userId` with the id of the element whichc you get in onclick event with `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: @Igle - if you're getting the `id` property you don't need the overhead of a new jQuery object - `this.id` will get it direct from the DOM in all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$.grep()`

```
var lis = [{'id':1, 'name':"honke"}, {'id':2, 'name':"hinke"}];
var found = $.grep(lis, function(el) {
  return el.id === 1;
});
alert(found[0].id);
```

Comment: three '===' is not working for me!!!!!, but in fiddle your code works fine, when have that in my code it wasnt working!, after i changed to "return el.id == 1", it works fine for me.any how thanks

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Javascript are essentially a dictionary, so if you're doing lots of lookups you can use that:

```
var users = { 1: {object1}, 2: {object2},: 3: {object2}};
```

Then you can do:

```
var user1 = users[span.id];
```

Alternatively you need to run a `for` loop through your array until you find the object where `.userId == span.id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery grep function:

```
var result = jQuery.grep(obj, function( obj, i ) {
    return ( obj.userId == 1 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to loop through each object to find it.

```
for(var user in users){
    if(users[user].userId == 1){
        console.log(users[user]);
        return users[user];
    }
}
```

here's the [js fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/3Dm6x/).

But for it to be more efficient you should [use a map as keith has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20190112/728610).